# PHP Composer Can't find autoloaded file

Tags: php, composer-php, autoload

I am trying to autoload a file and my PSR-4 autoloading worked fine locally however now that I am deploying to a baremetal server. It is not working and PHP states that it can't find the autoloaded file. This is the current error:

> Fatal error: Class 'Metabase\Models\Cron' not found in /usr/www/users/metabase/src/commands/ArticleFetchCron.php on line 25

My composer.json is as follows:

```
{
"require": {
    "vlucas/phpdotenv": "^2.4",
    "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "6.3",
    "monolog/monolog": "^1.23",
    "illuminate/http": "^5.7@dev"
},
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {"Metabase\\": "src/"}
}
}
```

The file that is having an issue is including the namespaces correctly as far as I know:

```
<?php

namespace Metabase\Commands;

// autoload composer
require_once(__DIR__ . '/../../vendor/autoload.php');

/**
 * Class ArticleFetchCron
 * @package Metabase\Commands
 */
use Metabase\Api\Requests\ArticleRequest;
use Metabase\Models\Cron;
use Metabase\Models\CronInterface;
use Metabase\Models\DatabaseAdapter;

class ArticleFetchCron extends Cron
implements CronInterface
```

I am just wondering if I have perhaps made a mistake with my composer.json file?

Comment: Are file names using the same case as class names? Do you have `Cron.php` or `cron.php`?

Comment: Filenames are the same case however the folders are in lowercase in this instance. so it's actually src/models/Cron.php however this wasn't an issue locally?

Comment: Because your local system is using a case insensitive file system such as NTFS.

Comment: Ah thanks! That makes sense! Should I rename the directories and generate a new classmap?

Comment: That's it. I'll compose an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The PSR-4 based class autoloader implemented by Composer, when asked to find `Metabase\Models\Cron`, looks for a file called `src\Models\Cron.php`. If your actual files are using a different case anywhere on the path such as `src\models\Cron.php` you'll get different results depending on whether the underlying file system is case sensitive or not. The reason is simple:

- If the file system is case sensitive it can physically contain two directories called `src\models` and `src\Models` and you're loading the wrong one.
- If it isn't, both paths are actually identical to all effects.

Double-check file names and rebuild the autoloader with `composer dump-autoload`.